# js combining objects only returns an id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am doing several finds in mongoose and then when I try to to combine the data it only displays the id and not the whole object. However, if I `console.log()` the object specifically it will display all of the contents.

Here are two of my finds in mongoose:

```
Project.find({ title: data.title }, function (err, projectObject) {
    if (err || !projectObject) cb(err, null);

    var project = new Object();
    for(var key in projectObject)
        if (undefined !== projectObject[key])
            project[key] = projectObject[key];

    Attachment.find({ projects: [ project._id ] }, function (err, attachments) {
        if (err) cb(err, null);

        if (attachments) 
            for (var i in attachments)
                project.attachments.push(attachments[i]);

        Location.find({ projects: [ project._id ] }, function (err, locations) {
            if (err) cb(err, null);

            if (locations)
                 for (var i in locations)
                    project.location.push(locations[i]);
        });
    });
});
```

If I now do a `console.log(project)` it will display:

```
{  
   '_id': 'ad5ffeb5a5a5fa763a64f3',
   'title': 'Tested project',
   'body': 'This is the content for the project.',
   __v: 0,
   'date_created': 'Wed Jan 07 2015 10:34:06   GMT-0600 (CST)',
   'location':[  
      'ad5ffeb5a5a5fa763a64f4'
   ],
   'moderator':[  
      'b041516116c16a1c5fb'
   ]
}
```

Now if I do `console.log(project.location)` this is what shows (off of the same object):

```
[  
   {  
      '_id': 'ad5ffeb5a5a5fa763a64f4',
      'name': 'home',
      'city': 'Columbia',
      'state': 'MO',
      'postcode': '65203',
      'country': 'US',
      'timezone': 'CST',
      '__v': 0,
      'geo':{  
         'type':'Point',
         'coordinates':[  
            -92.339894,
            38.962357
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

This is where I am confused because the object is there, but it only shows the id and not the whole object.

I am wondering if I am doing something wrong or even is there a better way to be doing this?

Comment: In this scenario that is a possibility, but is there a reason why this way is not working? I will add my other scenario to the question that populate would not work in.

Comment: I think you are right, would you turn your comment into an answer and I will accept it. Thank you!

Comment: It was just weird that it would still display the whole object when I `console.log(project.location)` I would have an easier time understanding if it only showed the idea like when I `console.log(project)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoose model instance docs are customized to generally constrain their accessible content to what's defined in their schema.  So if you want to freely manipulate their content, call [`lean()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) on your queries so that they return plain JavaScript objects instead.

```
Project.find({ title: data.title }).lean().exec(function (err, projectObject) { ...
```

But in this case it may be better to take advantage of Mongoose's [`population`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) support that can follow ObjectID references for you.